# Symfony 3: set value after submitting a form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I've a `form collection` and would like to set `field2` after submitting the form, depending on the value of `field1`. `field2` is not editable in the form, but required.

I tried every `FormEvent` *(FormEvents::)* but getting the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'field2' cannot be null

```
// AppBundle/Form/MyFormType.php

// ...
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $even) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (isset($data['field1'])) { // isset
        $field2 = $this->container->get('repository')->find($data['field1'])->getValue(); // service works

        $data['field2'] = $field2; // !!! doesn't work !!!              
        $data->setField2($field2); // !!! doesn't work !!!    
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: var_dump your field 2 and can you please post your db table

Comment: @g9m29 `$field2 = 'testvalue';` doesn't work either. Fieldname in the table is `field2`.

Comment: $data['field2'] = $field2;
        $data->setField2($data); !

Comment: if you're using POST_SUBMIT event, the form underlying data is already converted into model. If $data is supposed to be an entity, $data['field2'] = $field2 will for sure cause a fatal error ("object can't be used as array")

Comment: If I remember well you cannot modify any form data in the POST_SUBMIT event. Use PRE_SUBMIT instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this instead

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (isset($data['field1'])) {
        $field2 = $this->container->get('repository')->find($data['field1'])->getValue();

        $data['field2'] = $field2;              
        $event->setData($data); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you.